# Designing an iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I have come across many problems where an iterator is required.  Often, they are simple things where you already have an underlying data structure that you can defer to.  Other times, it gets more complex.

An example would be iterating over a BST without parent links using an in-order traversal.  This requires that you do something like:

- Create a stack in the constructor.
- Iterate to the left-most node.
- Store that there are more nodes to visit for easy return from hasNext().
- Store the next node to visit for easy return from next().

You can do the work to locate the next node in hasNext(), or in next().  You can also locate the first node in the constructor or in the first call to hasNext().

---

**My Question**

Are there standards or best practices for where to do most of the work in your iterator implementation?  Is one way "cleaner" than another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the contract of `Iterator` requires that `hasNext` return `true` if there are more elements, and `next` will throw an exception if `hasNext()==false`.

That means that there are two styles of using an iterator: `while (it.hasNext()) it.next()`, and `try { while (true) it.next(); } catch ...`. The latter is not a good practice, but it must be supported. I mentioned this because you cannot rely on `hasNext` having been called before `next`. I found this requirement is usually the culprit of otherwise unnecesary complexity in the implementation of iterators.

My choice is having a local variable with the `next` value. If `next==null` either the next value is unknown (and we must find it), or we have reached the end of the iteration (`hasNext()` will return `false` and `next()` will fail). Consider also that when the next value is unknown, it is possible that we are at the end of the iteration, but we haven't realized it yet.

```
Node next;

public boolean hasNext() {
   //if the next value already known, do nothing
   if (next==null) {         
     //otherwise lookup the next value
     next=findNext();
   }
   //return true if the next value was found
   return next!=null;
}

public Node next() {
  if (next==null&&!hasNext()) {
     //here we have reached the end of the iteration
     throw new NoSuchElementException();
  } else {
     //either we alredy knowed the next element 
     //or it was found by hasNext
     Node result = next;
     next=null;
     return result;
  }   
}

private Node findNext() {
   //the actual iteration
}
```

About the case of in-order traversal, you should keep a stack (note that the implementation of `Stack` is array-based and synchronized, probebly it is better to use a [`Dequeue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) such as `LinkedList`, which also supports `push` and `pop` as of Java 6), and auxiliary state for knowing how to resume the iteration each time that `findNext` is called.

Comment: In case when we use only next() method (without hasNext()): Is returning null bad practise in modern programming? Is it reason that we can call this model bad in general?

Comment: +1.  Also implementation should avoid error described in http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DMI_CALLING_NEXT_FROM_HASNEXT

Comment: @PiotrZych if you mean returning `null` for signalling the end of the iteration, I would consider it is bad design because an `Iterator` is not expected to be used in that way. An interface is not only a set of method signatures, but also the intended behavior of each method (the so called "contract").

Comment: Thank you; the "I mentioned this because you cannot rely on hasNext having been called before next. I found this requirement is usually the culprit of otherwise unnecesary complexity in the implementation of iterators." was most useful :)

Answer (score 2):

BST in-order traversal can be implemented by simple recursive DFS (left child -> node -> right child).

Answering your question: in general I think there are no "best practices" for iterator designing, because your data structures can be arbitrarily complex. Some common rules:

- Your iterator must support `hasNext()` and `next()` operations in any case. If your data structure is immutable (or removal is not typical), `remove()` method should throw `OperationNotSupportedException()`.
- `next()` method should check `hasNext()` value in the beginning of implementation and throw `NoSuchElementException` if `hasNext()` returns `false`.
- If your data structure has an iterator, it should implement `Iterable<Type>` interface and implement `public Iterator<Type> iterator()` method.
- So if you implement `Iterable` interface, the client code can use `foreach` operator to process your data structure. If such behavior is not desirable (for example, using `foreach` with bipartite graph structure can cause multiple client errors because it's not obvious on what are you iterating exactly), you should probably consider another way of implementing sequental iterations.
- If your data structure use list or set, your iterator implementation can use appropriate collection iterator.

In any case you should design your iterators with care. Each iterator is deeply connected with its data structure and should be designed together.